# Git shows ignored directory as untracked

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control, gitignore

I added `.vscode/` to `.gitignore` but I can still see it in `git status` as Untracked. I have neved committed it before so it's not a  key of the problem.

If i try to remove it from index by `git rm --cached .vscode`, i get an error: `fatal: pathspec '.vscode' did not match any files`.

I tried to remove and recreate `.vscode/`in order to force `.gitignore` to start working but it didnt help.

Have this problem with some other dirs aswell.

UPD:

- `.gitignore` location: `D:\Git\.gitignore`
- `.gitignore` content: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTwql.png
- Git root dir: `D:\Git`
- `.vscode/` location: `D:\Git\.vscode`

UPD1:

```
$ git status -uall
On branch opkm-pay-delay
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .vscode/.ropeproject/config.py
        .vscode/.ropeproject/objectdb
        .vscode/settings.json
```

Empty results of git check-ignore:

```
Paliyuk-PA@Paliyuk-PA MINGW64 /d/Git (opkm-pay-delay)
$ git check-ignore -v .vscode/.ropeproject/objectdb

Paliyuk-PA@Paliyuk-PA MINGW64 /d/Git (opkm-pay-delay)
$ git check-ignore -v .vscode/settings.json

Paliyuk-PA@Paliyuk-PA MINGW64 /d/Git (opkm-pay-delay)
$ git check-ignore -v .vscode/.ropeproject/config.py
```

Comment: Sounds like that the problem is somewhere you didn't show us. Show us the exact path of the files in the question and the exact content of the file

Comment: Have you spelled correctly the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: @user202729, updated description.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca, yeah, it should be correct. Added some description.

Comment: [`git check-ignore -v .vscode/`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) ?

Comment: @phd output: `.gitignore:137: .vscode/`

Comment: This means GIt ignores the directory due to the rule at line number 137. What does `git status` show?

Comment: @phd still the same problem :(
`$ git status

On branch opkm-pay-delay

Untracked files:

  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .vscode/`

Comment: Use `git status -uall` to show the actual files within `.vscode` that are untracked. You can then ask `git check-ignore -v` about those path names, with a more useful result. (Right now, this really does look like some sort of bizarre bug; perhaps with more details, we can find out more.)

Comment: I tried but failed to reproduce your situation. If the command torek suggests you run explain it, please share!

Comment: @torek , added the result to the description. Outputs blanks :\

Comment: Guys, thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, from this:

> ```
> $ git status -uall
> On branch opkm-pay-delay
> Untracked files:
>   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
>         .vscode/.ropeproject/config.py
>         .vscode/.ropeproject/objectdb
>         .vscode/settings.json
> ```

we know which files are problematic, and from this:

> ```
> Paliyuk-PA@Paliyuk-PA MINGW64 /d/Git (opkm-pay-delay)
> $ git check-ignore -v .vscode/.ropeproject/objectdb
> ```
>
> [results in no output]

we know that the `.vscode/` line (line 106 in the linked image) is not taking effect.  Finally, from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031795/git-shows-ignored-directory-as-untracked?noredirect=1#comment122029585_69041516), I know what the actual problem is:

> Also i found out that the old (broken) file weights almost twice as much as the new good one while their "text" content is the same.

The `.gitignore` file that *isn't* working is encoded in UTF-16 (probably UTF-16-LE, because Windows).  Git doesn't read such files.  Git expects the `.gitignore` contents to be UTF-8.  So, *none* of the UTF-16 content ends up actually *working*.

Recopying the contents to a new file apparently wrote out the *new* `.gitignore` as UTF-8, so that Git could read and understand it.  Windows probably also has file-conversion tools, although since I avoid Windows, I'm not sure what they might be.

Comment: Yeah, your are right. It was in UTF-16 LE with BOM. Resaving in UTF-8 fixed the broken file. Thanks :)

Comment: Omg...this was it

Answer (score 0):

I have just moved my `.gitignore` file to another dir, created a new empty one in my `D:\Git`, copy pasted the content of the original file to the new one and, **for some reason**, it finally worked!

So the answer is to recreate your `.gitignore` file  :|

Comment: Wow, it's just like the tech saying "reboot your computer", and having it work. How disappointing, because we'll never know what was really going on...

Comment: @joanis ,
I still have the broken file saved so i can share it if you want)
Also i found out that the old (broken) file weights almost twice as much as the new good one while their "text" content is the same. Looks like it has some bytes in it which cause the problem but those bytes are "invisible" in text representation.

Comment: @joanis: see my answer. The halving of the file size was the proof, although once I saw that `git check-ignore -v` was not applying the line, I *suspected*....

Comment: @torek So much more satisfying an answer! I'm glad this got figured out.